# run javascript function every time element is used?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to run a javascript function every time a certain element appears in HTML? Like for every time `h3` appears in my html file, I need a function to be called in javascript on load.

Comment: What do you mean 'used'? As in, appearing in the HTML structure, and you want the function to be called on load?

Comment: Yes sorry. I meant whenever it appears in the HTML structure and yes I want it to be called right when the page loads. Sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), then iterate:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  console.log(element[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. That is what I needed!

Comment: @SlinkyMation Make sure to accept answers!